# Mysql json column array value query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table that contains a json type column `history`, and the structure is this:

```
[
    {
        "admin_id": "1", 
        "process_time": "2017-6-6 14:14:14"
    }, 
    {
        "admin_id": "2", 
        "process_time": "2017-6-6 14:14:14"
    }
]
```

for every record's `history` column it may contain multiple elements in array. Now I want to build a query to select records which has specific id in `history` array. For example, I want to select all records which `history` array has `admin_id` equals to `1`. I don't know how to write this query, someone can help me? Thanks.